# EF Linq query is 100x slower than stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I ran a test execute a Linq query compared to a stored procedure call using both in EF `DataContext`. And it seems like the stored procedure call is around 100x faster - why is that?

LINQ example:

```
 var results = (from I in db.MyTable
                select I).toList();
```

Stored procedure:

```
  ....
  SELECT * 
  FROM myTable T
    INNER JOIN TABLE2
    INNER JOIN TABLE3
```

CALL to stored procedure

```
var results = this.Database.SQlQuery<MyModel>("spMyStorePro").ToList()
```

The Linq execution would take like 10-15 seconds, while the stored procedure call would take like 1-2 sec if not less.

the model contains several entities

```
 MyTableModel
      public int KEY {Get;set;}

      public virtual TABLE1 table1Info {get; set;}
      public virtual TABLE2 table2Info {get; set;}
```

Is this common or am I setting up my model incorrectly?

One thing I would mention is that my MODEL has a few nested models that may cause the slow performance.

UPDATED

So here is something interesting I found:

I grab the sql query from sql monitor that LINQ spits out.

it looks something like this

SELECT
       [EXtent1].COL1,
       [Extent2].COL2
   FROM table1 as extent1
       left outer join table 2 as extent2

if I execute the above query it takes 9 sec to execute each time.  The interesting is that if I remove COL2 from the select list, it executes in 2 secs.

WHy would removing a column from the select list improve the speed?  This is outside of EF and LINQ now, this is a question in sql

Comment: Have you tried Visual Studio Profiler? It helps you to find performance issues. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx

Comment: The first call is always the most expensive in EF. How did you measure it? What kind of statistic did you use? What was the sample size for the benchmark?

Comment: It worth to take a look at the generated query.

Comment: EF can create some incredibly horrid queries, especially when multiple entities are involved.  Sometimes re-writing your LINQ query can help.  Sometimes it's better to write your own SQL. Profile your query and see what it looks like.

Comment: Do you have lazy loading disabled? If so, and the table that you're querying has a bunch of FKs to other tables this query will take long, long time because it will be grabbing all of those entities as well.

Comment: @IronMan84 There is no lazy-loading if you do `.ToList();`. It gathers all documents and sub-documents recursivelly. That's probably the case here. His stored procedure just takes top-level objects, yet LINQ is joining everything underneath as well. @OP you should try this w/o doing `.ToList()`

Comment: 1-2 seconds vs. 10-15 seconds isn't exactly **100x slower** ..... more like 5-10x ......

Comment: @Marc so if I issue a ToList() it will load all the child objects?

Answer (score 0):

Things to review

- Is there any sort of WHERE clause in your stored procedure that is not in your EF query
- Is the stored procedure returning a nested hierarchy
- When you say that your "model has several nested models", have you tried configuring the relationships code-first, and excluding unnecessary children/descendants? See below...

```
var query = context.Query<Thing>(
       include: t => t.Child.Select(v => v.Grandchild))
       .Where(t => t.Foo == "bar"); // includes descendants

var query = context.Query<Thing>()
       .Where(t => t.Foo == "bar"); // excludes descendants
```